# Using SQL (Snowflake), I want to rank the coordinates for when each motorcycle is stationery (stationery time= time between trips) according to length

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sample data:

[Sample data][1]

```
        Time    Latitude Start  Longitude Start     Latitude End    Longitude End
Motorcycle 1    13:12   2.28079 77.70193    2.23239 33.72323
Motorcycle  1   14:40   2.23239 33.72323    9.23079 78.4289
Motorcycle  2   08:34   9.23079 78.4289 8.13433 12.70871
Motorcycle  2   18:20   8.13433 12.70871    7.23578 99.00093
Motorcycle  3   06:18   7.23578 99.00093    2.34079 75.44866
Motorcycle  3   10:00   2.34079 75.44866    1.25459 17.23253
Motorcycle  3   17:54   1.25459 17.23253    8.78088 99.00123
```

Essentially, I want to work out where the motorcycles spend most of their time parked (stationery). So, I want rank the coordinates of each motorcycle spends stationery spends time park in- by length ( time between trips= time parked/ stationery).
Stationery time is BETWEEN each trip. So, the end coordinates from one trip are where the motorcycle would have been stationery. They remain there until the next trip begins.

No idea how to query using SQL. Any ideas? Not really sure where to start- very much a beginner with SQL

Comment: Your hyperlink isn't working: could you please update this?

Comment: Hi sorry about that. I've pasted it in now.

Comment: No problem. Just check before you post that everything is as you would like it to be :)

Comment: Will do. First day using this. Will make sure I do going forward

Comment: No problem, just some advice :)

Answer (score 0):

So there are two steps one is to filter "has moved"/"stationary" rows, which to be honest I am not 100% if that is what you are presenting in your data so we will start with a filter to get those (within a threshold)

```
SELECT name, duration, start_lat, start_lon
FROM table
/* where start is within 100m of start */
WHERE haversine(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat,end_lon) > 0.1
```

and now we have our "stationary" rows we are want to rank the rows per `name` to find the longest of each, which can be done via a row_number

```
SELECT name, duration, start_lat, start_lon
FROM table
/* where start is within 100m of start */
WHERE haversine(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat,end_lon) > 0.1 
QUALIFY row_number() over( partition by name order by duration desc) = 1
```

which is the same as:

```
SELECT name, duration, start_lat, start_lon
FROM (
    SELECT name, duration, start_lat, start_lon
        ,row_number() over( partition by name order by duration desc) as rn
    FROM table
    /* where start is within 100m of start */
    WHERE haversine(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat,end_lon) > 0.1 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

New facts: If each row is the "moving section" to get the details of the between rows is.

```
SELECT vehicle_id, 
    lag(time) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_time,
    time as stat_end_time,
    date_diff('seconds', stat_start_time, stat_end_time) as stat_duration_s,
    lag(end_lat) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_lat,
    lag(end_lon) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_lon,
    start_lat as stat_end_lat,
    start_lon as stat_end_lon
FROM table
```

now we have a table of "stationary" entries, you can do what you wish with it.

thus the longest startionary period per vehicle becomes:

```
WITH data (vehicle_id, time, start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon) AS (
  SELECT column1, column2::time, column3, column4, column5, column6  FROM VALUES
    ('Motorcycle  1', '13:12', 2.28079, 77.70193, 2.23239, 33.72323),
    ('Motorcycle  1', '14:40', 2.23239, 33.72323, 9.23079, 78.42890),
    ('Motorcycle  2', '08:34', 9.23079, 78.42890, 8.13433, 12.70871),
    ('Motorcycle  2', '18:20', 8.13433, 12.70871, 7.23578, 99.00093),
    ('Motorcycle  3', '06:18', 7.23578, 99.00093, 2.34079, 75.44866),
    ('Motorcycle  3', '10:00', 2.34079, 75.44866, 1.25459, 17.23253),
    ('Motorcycle  3', '17:54', 1.25459, 17.23253, 8.78088, 99.00123)
)
SELECT vehicle_id,
    stat_duration_s,
    stat_start_lon,
    stat_start_lat
FROM (
    SELECT vehicle_id, 
        lag(time) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_time,
        time as stat_end_time,
        datediff('seconds', stat_start_time, stat_end_time) as stat_duration_s,
        lag(end_lat) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_lat,
        lag(end_lon) over (partition by vehicle_id order by time) as stat_start_lon,
        start_lat as stat_end_lat,
        start_lon as stat_end_lon
    FROM data
)
QUALIFY row_number() over( partition by vehicle_id order by stat_duration_s desc nulls last) = 1
```

gives:

| VEHICLE_ID | STAT_DURATION_S | STAT_START_LON | STAT_START_LAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Motorcycle 1 | 5280 | 33.72323 | 2.23239 |
| Motorcycle 2 | 35160 | 12.70871 | 8.13433 |
| Motorcycle 3 | 28440 | 17.23253 | 1.25459 |

Comment: Hi , sorry I should have been more clear. There are no stationery roads. even a minute difference in coordinates indicates a journey. Stationery time is BETWEEN each row. so the end coordiantes  of the journey are where the motorcycle spends its stationery time before then embarking on another journey. That's what I've having trouble extracting.

Comment: ah, very cool, that not hard to handle

Comment: * no stationery rows.

Comment: I just can't work out how to separate distance between trips into a new column and arrange by motorcycle.

Comment: if a trip is your row, there should be no distance between rows. otherwise that also is a trip.

Comment: Sorry I must have copied this incorrectly. Let me re-do the question.

Comment: but the distance between this row and the prior is `haversine(start_lat,start_lon, lag(end_lat)over(partion by vehicle_id order by time), lag(end_log)over(parition by vehicle_id order by time))`

Comment: you just need to replace `vehicle_id` with a stable token for each vehicle, and you need a wall clock/time to order the trips, for the lag to work. and if you want the distance to next trip, ether flip to `lead` or flip the `order` (but the latter is more hard to read, thus should be avoided)

Comment: OK, thank you. Will research what you have mentioned. quite new to SQL so will devote today to research.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?